# How to show/hide an element on interval

Tags: javascript

So I have this button which onclick has a function that shows an element. Now I want to add a function by default that will hide this same element after some given interval.
So if I click this button, div-container will be displayed after .5s. Now I want to check that if this div-container is displayed, the users can read it and then it will be hidden. So It's more like an alert.

Heres my snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click",function(){

        let clock = setInterval(() => {
            clearInterval(clock)
            clock = null
            document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'block'
        }, 500)
})


// this is where I tried to make it hide after some given interval but it's not working
var alert = document.getElementById('alert');
if(alert.style.display==="block"){

        let clock = setInterval(() => {
            clearInterval(clock)
            clock = null
            document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'none'
        }, 500)
}
```

```html
<button id="mybtn">Show/hide</button>

<div id="alert" style="display:none"><h3>this is an alert</h3></div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `setTimeout`?

Comment: "it's not working": Please provide details.

Comment: You don't need to repeat execution here. You should take a look at `setTimeout()` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: @ScottHunter, the details are provided on the snippet code. That's why I added it so you can try it and see why "it's not working".

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I haven't tried using it but I'll give it a try rn. Thank you.

Comment: @Tom Found a solution to this thanks to setTimeOut, thank you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `setTimeout`.

```js
let clockTimeout = null

document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click",function(){
        document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'block'
        clearTimeout(clockTimeout)
        clockTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'none'
        }, 1500)
})
```

```html
<button id="mybtn">Show/hide</button>

<div id="alert" style="display:none"><h3>this is an alert</h3></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your event you have first to show the alert div container. then you set the Timeout. inside the timeout function you hide the alert box again.

```js
document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click",function(){
        document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'block'
        let clock = setInterval(() => {
            document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'none'
        }, 5000)
})
```

```html
<button id="mybtn">Show/hide</button>

<div id="alert" style="display:none"><h3>this is an alert</h3></div>
```